# a variation of TSP : limit time, visit as many nodes as possible

Tags: algorithm, routes, combinatorics, traveling-salesman

again let's use the salesman context:

if the salesman is not required to visit ALL customers, but is given a time constraint, in which he must vist as many customers as possible. how can we find the best route?

an even more slightly advanced version is, say each customer is marked with a monetary gain, so our salesman wants to maximize the total monetary gain from those customers that he actually visits, as long as he finishes visiting them within the time constraint

I tried to search for some research papers. but the closest I found is the work on k-TSP, in which the salesman is asked to maximize the total gain on a path less than k hops long. this is quite different since the edge time cost does not exist, or is just 1.

anybody knows of any existing research work on this problem?

thanks
Yang

Comment: The second variation you mention sounds like the Prize-Collecting TSP.

Comment: The second variation is _almost_ Prize-Collecting TSP -- PCTSP doesn't usually include a time constraint. This is more like a prize-collecting vehicle routing problem (VRP) with only a single vehicle allowed. Not sure if that variation has appeared in the literature but maybe.

Comment: thanks guys. PCTSP is an important reference

Comment: Have you find a solution to the first variation? if you did, could you tell me what algorithm is suitable for it. thx

Answer (score 3):

Look at [jsprit](http://jsprit.github.io/). It lets you define:

- a traveling salesman with a time constraint, i.e. earliestStart and latestArrival at start/depot location,
- profits for each customer to visit and
- an objective function that considers these profits.

Thus jsprit determines the customers you need to visit to max. your profits considering transport costs and time constraints. All other customers end up in an unassigned job list. Note that jsprit uses an heuristic approach to solve such a problem.

Comment: Stefan: thanks for the pointer. 2 questions:
1) if I have different profit for each customer, the Service class needs to be subclassed, right? currently Service does not have getProfit() or anything like that
2) if the profit for a node is very large, we might get negative cycles. so does the algorithm enforce that a node is visited at most once?